# Visual Studio Code, PHP Project, Global include/Autoload/Autoinclude a functions.php file just for intellisense

Tags: php, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm relative new to vs code so sorry if this might be a trivial question.

I have a functions.php file in my filesystem which has a list of available functions and the required parameters (just the function list, not the implementation) which i want to use for autocompletion/intellisense in vs code during editing.

I don't want to to require_once "/functions.php" in my scripts but as i just want to use it for intellisense in vs code i want it to be automatically loaded in the background but not being part of my php script.

Maybe something like a global include or autoinclude in the background.

Would be thankful for any help.

Best regards
Thorsten

Comment: Found a solution in using the "PHP Intellisense - Crane" plugin (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HvyIndustries.crane#overview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in using the "PHP Intellisense - Crane" plugin (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HvyIndustries.crane#overview)